# Fix duplicate query string in nginx

Tags: nginx

I've got a strange case where my app is now for some reason appending a duplicate query string onto a URL that already has one.  I don't have the access or the time to dig into the application code right now, but I do have access to Nginx configs.

What I need is a rewrite rule that will ignore the duplicate query string, ie

`http://foo.com?test=bar?test=bar` will redirect to `http://foo.com?test=bar`

Is this even possible?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here, add this inside your `server` block, before any other `location` or `if`:

```
if ($query_string ~ ^([^?]+)\?\1$) {
  set $clean $1;
  rewrite . $uri?$clean?;
}
```

It's quite tricky to get right, because there are more than a few obscure behaviours:

- `$query_string` is the query string without the initial `?`
- the `\1` in the regexp matches a second copy of the first group `(...)`
- you need to save `$1` into a new variable because rewrite will overwrite it
- you need to use `$uri` and not `$request_uri` in the rewrite, because the latter contains a copy of the original query string
- you need to add a trailing `?` to the rewrite, otherwise the rewrite would append a copy of the original query string! (that's probably the most obscure bit of Nginx syntax, ever)

The simple form of `rewrite` (without the `redirect` flag) should be enough for most applications, plus it doesn't require an additional round-trip to the browser.

If it does not work for you, you can try using the `$clean` query string into the appropriate backend directive (such as `fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING` and such) or, as a last resort, issuing a browser redirect using the `redirect` rewrite flag.